# Which is the maximum valid value for relativeHeight attribute in wp:anchor tag?

Tags: xml, format, openxml, docx, docx4j

I'm inserting elements in a *docx* document via *docx4j* and I want my new elements to be on front (always visible over other elements that could overlap).

I think that in order to accomplish my target I have to set to the maximum value the **relativeHeight** attribute of the **wp:anchor** tag.

So my question is: which is the maximum value allowed?

Documentation at http://www.officeopenxml.com/drwPicFloating.php doesn't specify it.

Comment: It's seems that the maximum valid value is 4294967295 (brute force by myself). If someone has any more accurate answer, feel free to share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the spec (see eg [anchor_2.html](http://webapp.docx4java.org/OnlineDemo/ecma376/DrawingML/anchor_2.html)) it is defined by the XML Schema to be unsignedInt datatype, the max value for which is what can fit in a word of 32 bits (which, happily, matches your empirical finding).

I didn't see anything in [MS-OE376] or [MS-OI29500] which adds to this.